# Include .jar-File in PHPJAVA Bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge, mpxj

I try to load the "Tasks" from a .mpp-File. 
If I get the current date by `java.util.Date` it works very fine, to access `JAVA` but if i try to access the MPPReader I get the error:

```
CreateInstance failed: new net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

This is the code to my test case.

```
define("JAVA_SERVLET", false);
define("JAVA_HOSTS", 9267);

$mpxjPath = getcwd()."/libs/java/mpxj-5.6.0.jar";
exec("java -cp $mpxjPath");
require_once("libs/java/Java.inc");

$date = new java('java.util.Date');
echo $date;

$project = new java('net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader');
```

This is the output in the browser

```
Wed Feb 01 08:53:43 CET 2017
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader VM: 1.7.0_55@http://java.oracle.com/" at:
    #-15 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    #-14 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 ...
```

The output shows, that the java is reachable. But how can I access the MPPReader ?

---

**Update**

Server: CentOS 7

This is the code in my `index.php` right now.

```
<?php
define("JAVA_HOSTS", 9267);
define("JAVA_SERVLET", false);

require_once("libs/java/Java.inc");

echo "<pre>";
$date = new java('java.util.Date');
echo $date;

$project = new java('net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader');

?>
```

Run `Standalone` command on `CentOS 7`

```
java -cp "ext/JavaBridge.jar:libs/java/mpxj-5.6.0.jar" php.java.bridge.Standalone SERVLET:9267
```

This is the error.

```
Thu Feb 02 07:11:45 CET 2017PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new java.net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader VM: 1.7.0_55@http://java.oracle.com/" at:
#-15 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
#-14 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
#-13 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
#-12 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
#-11 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
#-10 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
#-9 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
#-8 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
#-7 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
#-6 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518)
#-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445)
#-4 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458)
#-3 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
#-2 php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(Co in http://127.0.0.1:9267/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your attempt to load the `mpxj-5.6.0.jar`, I noticed you tried to make it available to the JVM from the client side (PHP):

```
$mpxjPath = getcwd()."/libs/java/mpxj-5.6.0.jar";
exec("java -cp $mpxjPath");
require_once("libs/java/Java.inc");
```

The idea looks appealing, but sadly cannot work that way.

---

Remember the java-bridge is made of two parts, the client (Java.inc / PHP) and server (PHPJavaBridge / Generally a servlet). So if you want to add a library to the classpath, it must be done on the server side (available to the JVM).

From your code example (`define("JAVA_SERVLET", false)`), I assume you're not starting the bridge through Tomcat/servlet env, but with the standalone server. In this scenario, you'll have to add the `*.jar` on the classpath when starting the server.

You'll end up doing something approx like this to start the server :

```
$ java -cp "./JavaBridge.jar:/path/to/mpxj-5.6.0.jar" php.java.bridge.Standalone SERVLET:9267
```

> edit: *replace /path/to/ in by the correct location of the jar.*

---

If you're working on Linux/Mac, have a look at the [pjbserver-tools](https://github.com/belgattitude/pjbserver-tools) project. It provides a php-wrapper around the standalone server where you can easily configure deps.

Just keep aware of two things:

- Servlet mode (.war/tomcat) is the way to go if you intend to use it in production. If you're unsure about how it works, see the [pjb-starter-gradle](https://github.com/belgattitude/pjb-starter-gradle) which contains documentation.
- The *older* `Java.inc` won't run on PHP7 and support won't probably be continued... At least take time to **consider** using the reworked client: [soluble-japha](https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha). It might even be easier to work with it, but of course, as the author, I'm biased. Check for yourself ;)

---

Note for servlet tomcat:

For servlet tomcat install, same idea applies. Just make sure your .jar file(s) are present in `WEB-INF\lib`directory. See also the [unoffical php-java-bridge fork](https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge) to get the latest .war template.

Comment: well, add the .jar-File to the classpath in the server. but If i run the index.php page i recieve the same error `An exception occured: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader`.

Comment: So it's not yet made ;) Can you update your problem description and include how you start the server (command line used if applicable), platform (windows/unix) and clarify the mode Tomcat/Servlet or StandAlone ? This way, I might be more precise in answer... too much guess right now ;) _(could be nice also to be sure what you call index.php, Is it your script example ? just to be sure)_

Comment: Just made a small edit to include the path for the jar in the command. Can you try ?

Comment: Well.. is fixed! :) The classpath was shown on the java direct and not on the folder!! now it works! Thank you for your support!

Comment: Great! if you use composer really consider the updated client https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha. Compatible with the phpjavabridge server, a little more verbose but you'll avoid a lot of issues later. Just my 2 cents ;)